# CodeIgniter make file uploads optional

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have found some examples of making the uploads optional but so far it hasn't work for me. I might have missed something so I'm hoping someone might catch it? This is the link to what I am following

https://blog.smalldo.gs/2013/03/optional-file-upload-field-codeigniter/

So far I am able to edit the product if I don't upload a file but if I upload a file, I get a you did not select a file to upload error. Please help. Thank you.

Controller

```
public function editProduct(){
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductname', 'Name', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductdescription', 'Description', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductprice', 'Price', 'trim|required');

      $inputproductname = $this->input->post('inputproductname');
      $inputproductdescription = $this->input->post('inputproductdescription');
      $inputproductprice = $this->input->post('inputproductprice');
      $inputdateadded = date('Y-m-d');
      $inputcurrentproductid = $this->input->post('inputcurrentproductid');
      $inputcurrentproductstatus = $this->input->post('inputcurrentproductstatus');

      $config['upload_path'] = $this->getProductImageFolderPath();
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png'; 
      $config['max_size'] = 3000;  
      $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
      $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
      $config['file_name'] = $inputproductname;
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
            $data['product'] = $this->ProductsModel->getProduct($inputcurrentproductid);
            $data['edit'] = "true";
            $data['message']='';
            $data['inputcurrentproductid'] = $inputcurrentproductid;
            $data['inputcurrentproductstatus'] = $inputcurrentproductstatus;

            $this->load->view('control/controlMenu/navigationLink');
            $this->load->view('control/controlProducts/productDetail',$data);
            $this->load->view('control/controlMenu/navigationJquery');
        }else{
          if(isset($_FILES['upload'])&&$_FILES['upload']['size']>0){
              if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                  $this->session->set_flashdata('Form',$this->upload->display_errors());
                  redirect('Control/ProductDetail/'.$inputcurrentproductid."/".$inputcurrentproductstatus);
              }else{
                  $extension = $this->upload->data('file_ext');
                  $productdetails = array(
                    'name'=>$inputproductname,
                    'description'=>$inputproductdescription,
                    'price'=>$inputproductprice,
                    'imagePath'=>$config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'].$extension,
                    'dateAdded'=>$inputdateadded
                  );
                  $this->db->trans_start();
                  $this->ProductsModel->editProduct($inputcurrentproductid,$productdetails);
                  $error = $this->db->error();
                  $this->db->trans_complete();
                  if($this->db->trans_status()===false){

                  }else{
                      $this->session->set_flashdata('Form', $inputproductname . ' has been altered on the database');
                      redirect('/Control/Products');
                  }
                  if($error!=''){ 
                      $this->session->set_flashdata('Form',$error["message"]);
                      redirect('/Control/Products');
                  }
              }
          }else{
              $productdetails = array(
                  'name'=>$inputproductname,
                  'description'=>$inputproductdescription,
                  'price'=>$inputproductprice
              );
              $this->db->trans_start();
              $this->ProductsModel->editProduct($inputcurrentproductid,$productdetails);
              $error = $this->db->error();
              $this->db->trans_complete();
              if($this->db->trans_status()===false){

              }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('Form', $inputproductname . ' has been altered on the database');
                    redirect('/Control/Products');
              }
              if($error!=''){ 
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('Form',$error["message"]);
                    redirect('/Control/Products');
              }  
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell the upload library from which field to take the file.

```
$this->upload->do_upload() // <-- no argument for this method provided
```

If no field name is provided, by default it tries to get the file from `userfile` field [[docs]](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::do_upload), but your file input is called `upload` as seen in the code sample. So you should do

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload("upload")){
```

Also, note that on the client side the form with file field should be declared as

```
<form method="post" action="some_action" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
```

otherwise file field will be empty too.